# Searching for old .Net librairies

Tags: .net, installation, infragistics, componentone

I am looking for old .net third parties libraries.

The situation I am in is that we need to work with an old source base for a client that has the code sources but not the third parties libraries.

We did contact the old libraries provider but they told us that they do not keep track of those old installs.  Too bad for us then!

I am looking for the installation kit for :

```
• Component One v.1.1.20024.64 (somewhere circa 2002)

    o C1.C1Zip.dll --> Version 1.1.20023.5 (runtime version v1.0.3705)

    o C1.Common.dll --> Version 1.0.20023.101 (runtime version v1.0.3705)

    o C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.dll --> Version 1.1.20023.44 (runtime version v1.0.3705)

• Infragistics v4.3

    o The Windows Forms libraries.
```

Do you know of ANY web site, ftp, company where we could find those libraries?

Do you still have those install kit (in which case you could be a good Samaritan and drop on an FTP ?)

Do you have any strategy / idea as to what we could do in this situation ?

Thanks a lot,

Patrick

Comment: "the old libraries provider": as you've used the singular a clarification: do you mean Component One and Infragistics, or some reseller? If some reseller, have you contacted Infragistics and Component One *directly*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well have you searched the GAC of any machine that's able to run the program?

Comment: Or the install directory, even. The DLLs have to be one place or the other.